# Why am I getting an error when calling the `separate` function with a column?

Tags: r, tidyr

This is the format of the data I have in my data frame
[image: Current data]

I want my data frame to look something like this [image: Desired data]

This is what I am trying to do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

separate(data1, col = data1$Description, into = c("Location","ID","Date"),sep = ':')
```

This is the error I am getting
Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript. x Subscript `var` has size 10 but must be size 1. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Bit hard to test without your data, but I suspect you don't need the `data1$` in your `col` argument.  Does it work with just `col = Description` (or  `col = 'Description'`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comment, the problem is linked with the way you refer to your `Description` column.

See:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Description = c("location1:52:2018-10-20", "location2:59:2018-14-24")
)
# working
tidyr::separate(df, col = Description, into = c("Location", "ID", "Date"), sep = ":")
#>    Location ID       Date
#> 1 location1 52 2018-10-20
#> 2 location2 59 2018-14-24
tidyr::separate(df, col = "Description", into = c("Location", "ID", "Date"), sep = ":")
#>    Location ID       Date
#> 1 location1 52 2018-10-20
#> 2 location2 59 2018-14-24
tidyr::separate(df, col = 1, into = c("Location", "ID", "Date"), sep = ":")
#>    Location ID       Date
#> 1 location1 52 2018-10-20
#> 2 location2 59 2018-14-24

# not working
tidyr::separate(df, col = df$Description, into = c("Location", "ID", "Date"), sep = ":")
#> Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
#> x Subscript `var` has size 2 but must be size 1.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In case you are also interested in a *base R* solution, you can try this
:

```
data1 <- data.frame(Description = c("location1:48:2018-10-23", "location2:83:2018-01-05"), Temp = c(-0.9381736, 1.1714643))
data1
#              Description   Temp
# 1 location1:48:2018-10-23 -0.9381736
# 2 location2:83:2018-01-05  1.1714643
```

```
data2 <- data1$Description|> strsplit(":") |> sapply(c) |> t() |> as.data.frame() |> cbind(data1$Temp)
colnames(data2) <- c('Location', 'ID', 'Date', 'Temp')

data2
#    Location ID       Date       Temp
# 1 location1 48 2018-10-23 -0.9381736
# 2 location2 83 2018-01-05  1.1714643
```

*Note that the native pipe `|>` is only available in R 4.1.0 or newer version.*